# Network Error (Tcp_error)

Tags: php, mysql, networking

I have created one website and its working perfectly.
But sometimes i got error

> Network Error (tcp_error).
>   A communication error occurred: ""
>   The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Please tell us what is exact reason .. so we are getting error.

Language : PHP, Mysql . Engine Myisam, Apache , Linux

Comment: Maybe the server you site is on is "too busy"? Likely the server doesn't accept many concurrent connections, so it's nothing wrong with your website.

Answer (score 0):

You might look for what http error its returning for futhrer trace.